# How to prevent style-change on login-button

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using Facebook's own API to give users an alternative login-method in an app. I'm using their own `FBSDKLoginButton` to do so.

When a user enters the login-view in the app, it looks like this:

[image: Before logging in with FB]

When the user clicks this button, it will open the Facebook-app (or a browser, if the app isn't available), and prompt the user to log in. After a successful login, it should return to my app. Which it does. The problem is, the Facebook-button now looks like this:

[image: After logging in using FB]

I don't know why or how to prevent it..
It's not the end of the world for me, as the view will disappear right after this, but it IS kinda annoying.

I have not done anything to the button. I only dragged an `UIButton` to the `Storyboard`, and set it to be subclass of `FBSDKLoginButton`. In the code, I have only set `btnFacebookLogin.delegate = self`, as well as implementing the delegates in my `loginViewController.h`.

I tried adding `btnFacebookLogin.clipsToBounds = YES` to no avail. The backgroundColor of the entire button does nothing. I believe it has to do with the button's layer, however I'm reluctant to search through its layers and find it to change something. There has to be a reason for this?

To be clear, I want the style to be the same, instead of changing to this transparent text and.. 'discoloration'..

**Update**

Actually, the result changes when adding `clipsToBounds = YES` to the button. This is the following result:

[image: Using clipsToBounds]

The image is positioned and sized using constraints in Storyboard. Maybe this has something to do with it.. The white square behind the original result might resemble the width the button would've had if it was used on an <=iPhone 5s.. It is, however, strange that it's not aligned properly.. it's not centered.

Comment: It's best to submit a bug report at developers.facebook.com/bugs and provide a sample app with a repro. That way we can look into what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the UIButton property **showsTouchWhenHighlighted** is set to false. If this does not work make sure the property **adjustsImageWhenHighlighted** is also set to false.

Comment: Neither of those did anything I'm afraid.. A good thought though, but the resulting design is not the same as the highlight. If I click the button after the design-change, it still has its own hightlight-style (and the hightlight of the first button does not look like the result in the second image).

Comment: Actually.. adding these did nothing at all. It still DOES highlight on touch/hold. Maybe the FBSDK is overriding them..

Comment: Did you change those thru code or thru the storyboard? It is possible that the subclass will disregard those properties. Let me check the Login button code to see if they do override these.

Comment: I changed them in `viewDidLoad`. That's the only place I directly access the button at all, except from the delegate method. I have put a `return;` in the top of the delegate-method, so I have verified that it changes before the delegate kicks in.

Comment: Found out something, see updated answer. (notice the second image has changed)